# How to read Scientific notaions?

Tags: notation

My question is short and not very hard. is `2.203226E0>0.0059867`?
In other words, can anyone tell me how to convert `2.203226E0` into a float without integer side?

Comment: `E0` is a free ticket. It allows you to just throw off the scientific notation's exponent. This means that what you said at first is true.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Got it, imagine if it was `E1`. Then how to reform it?

Comment: `E1`: shift the decimal point one place right, then throw off exponent. `E-1` is the same, but shift the point one place left. In general, `En` shifts the dot `n` places right.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thus `2.203226E1` is equal to `22.03226`?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Care to send an answer so I make my question useful to the other audiences?

Comment: A question can be useful, even if it is not answered.

Comment: But dont you think a question with no answer would attract much less users?

Comment: Not necesssarily. For example, the questions I read are almost always not answered (with some exceptions).